# github fork confusion

Tags: github, merge, fork, local, repository

I followed this https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo post to clone a repository locally. After doing that another developer created a branch to the main repository and added some features to that branch. My question is

1. How do I get that branch into my fork.
2. Can I get that missing branch again to my local using **git pull upstream/missing_branch** command?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a remote repo '`upstream`' in the local repo (which has for origin your fork)

[image: upstream and fork]

([`git remote` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))

```
git remote add upstream url://upstream/repo
```

The [OP opensourcelover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2068301/opensourcelover) mentions [seeing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956343/github-fork-confusion/15957211#comment22741620_15957211):

```
git remote -v, 

origin git@github.com:username/project.git (fetch) 
origin git@github.com:username/project.git (push) 
upstream git@github.com:username/project.git (fetch) 
upstream git@github.com:username/project.git (push)
```

If your `origin` is the same as your `upstream` remote repo, you can replace that url by the https one for that `upstream`:

```
git remote set-url upstream https://github.com/originalDevName/originalRepoName
```

That way, you can `git fetch upstream` and get the new branch.

If you need to *work* on that new branch, you can now declare it:

```
git branch -u upstream/foo foo
```

See "[How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309)".

Comment: I did that. when I run git remote -v, I get this

origin git@github.com:username/project.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:username/project.git (push)
upstream git@github.com:username/project.git (fetch)
upstream git@github.com:username/project.git (push)

so when I try running

 git fetch upstream

it doesn't pull anything.

Comment: so when I run 

git branch -u upstream/foo foo on the my project level directory, is that going to overrite my existing files ?

Comment: @opensourcelover no: only declare a new branch. You can then checkout that new branch (and your working tree will be updated), or merge it to your current branch.